# Git merge, add all updated files

Tags: git, merge

I just merged two repositories, and I had to update probably 50+ files. To complete the merge I need to add back the updated files, I get this error:

```
error: merge is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

I have resolved all of the conflicts in the code, is there a command that will add all updated files or do I have to go file by file and add it manually?

Comment: Use `git add`, `git commit`. You have to pass the files explicitly to `git add`, `git add -u` won't work.

Comment: You can use `git add .` to add all files and then do a `git commit`

Comment: During the merge, though? I get this error:
fatal: You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you merge.
\

Comment: Please show the results of `git status`.

Comment: @ruby_noobie No, you do `git add .` then `git commit` and then the merge

Comment: This worked. If you want to put is as solution I will mark top answer. Or maybe I will just delete the whole question because I have officially overthought one of the first things that I ever learned about git. Thanks!

Comment: @ruby_noobie Added the answer, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in this order:

`git add .`
`git commit`
`git merge`